# Pygame fill isn't updating until bringing it off-screen

Tags: python, pygame

When I run the code, the screen is shown as black, until I bring the Pygame window off of my desktop window, then it shows both the white fill and the red rectangle. How do I make it just show the fill without bringing it off of my desktop screen?

```
import pygame

pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1200, 800))
run = True

def block(color, x, y, l, w):
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, color, pygame.Rect(x, y, l, w))

while run:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False
    screen.fill((255, 255, 255))
    block((255, 0, 0), 150, 150, 50, 50)
    pygame.display.flip
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The last line `pygame.display.flip` is incorrect. That line should be a function call, but instead you are simply referencing to the function object and then doing nothing. Instead, replace the last line with `pygame.display.flip()`.